# PlayonLinux not prompting Wine Mono and Gecko installation for Acrobat DC

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I recently installed PlayonLinux on Ubuntu 20.04 to get Adobe Acrobat DC. During my first attempt to install it, I got a pop up from PlayonLinux that asked me to install Wine Mono and Gecko and so I did. But after installation, Adobe Acrobat DC did not work properly (a pop said that it had encountered some serious issue) and so I first uninstalled it from PlayonLinux and then uninstalled PlayOnLinux itself. Then I installed it again.

I used the following commmands for uninstallation:

`sudo apt-get purge playonlinux`

`sudo apt-get purge wine64`

However, during my next installation of Acrobat DC from PlayonLinux, I didn't get any pop that asked me to install Wine Mono and Gecko. And I got the same error with Acrobat as before. The folders labelled Mono and Gecko inside the wine folder of the .PlayOnLinux directory are also empty. Is this a problem with Acrobat DC ? How do I correct this?

Comment: You installed 3 things and then removed the second 2 surprise it did not work. I would start with remove Arcobat and reboot. You then can try installing it again.

Comment: I uninstalled Acrobat from PlayOnLinux before I uninstalled the latter

Comment: That should be said in the question.

Comment: You should read this link and re think using Acrobat. https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

Comment: Thanks, got it. But about Wine Mono and Gecko - how do I resolve that issue with respect to PlayOnLinux? Are those folders supposed to be empty?